# Building a REST API for a dashboard with charts

Tags: mongodb, rest, google-bigquery

I'm coming today for your help because i'm working on a project which requires the implementation of a REST API that query aprox 80million of indicators (documents) in a MongoDB Collection. Each indicator follow this "schema":

```
{
  indicator_type: string,
  indicator_name: string,
  entityId:       string,
  date:           date,
  stringDate:     string,
  value:          double,
}
```

Actually there is an API built in JAVA but it consumes a lot of CPU, memory and sometimes there are timeouts or the responses take a lot of time, that's the reason with need to remake it. So my questions are this ones:

1. How bad is saving the indicators like this and are there some patterns to save this kind of data?
2. Which programming language can you recommend to develop this kind of endpoints?
3. We think much of our problem is about the database, so we are thinking to move to Google BigQuery. Can BigQuery help to get fasters responses?
4. If BigQuery is not a great answer which other tools can you recommend to this use case?

What we are trying to achieve are responses like this one.

```
{
  "totalConversions": {
     "visitorPedestrianAverageConversion":5.847142857142858,
     "ticketVisitorAverageConversion":0
  },
  "series":[
    {
      "data":[126,124,100,111,74,99,141],
      "id":"indicator_type",
      "type":"spline"
    },
    {
      "data": [1925,2377,1873,1769,1067,2460,2139],
      "id":"indicator_type",
      "type":"spline"
    },
    {
      "data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      "id":"indicator_type",
      "type":"spline"
    },
    {
      "yAxis":1,
      "data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      "id":"indicator_type",
      "type":"column"
    },
    {
      "data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      "id":"indicator_type",
      "type":"spline"
    },
    {
      "yAxis":2,
      "data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      "id":"indicator_type",
      "type":"scatter"
    },
    {
      "yAxis":2,
      "data":[6.55,5.22,5.34,6.27,6.94,4.02,6.59],
      "id":"indicator_type",
      "type":"scatter"
    },
    {
      "yAxis":2,
      "data":[100,100,100,100,100,100,100],
      "id":"indicator_type",
      "type":"spline"
    }
  ],
  "categories":["Lun 02/03/2020","Mar 03/03/2020","Mié 04/03/2020","Jue 05/03/2020","Vie 06/03/2020","Sáb 07/03/2020","Dom 08/03/2020"]
}
```

Comment: Hi Sergio, is the CPU load due to Mongo scanning the full table in order to fetch the right document? have you tried indexing some columns? BigQuery can certainly be a much faster querying engine (that you don't need to manage) and you can basically build a wrapper around its own API to make it simpler to your usecase.

Comment: @Sergio Fonseca, Regarding your first 2 questions I would say it depends on you experience as a developer. As for the questions 3 and 4, BigQuery is a very good option because it is a massive scale, non-ops data wharehouse product which runs primarily SQL queries against your data. You can check BigQuery prices, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing). Also its methods for loading?streaming data into it, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data). Do you have any other questions?

Comment: @FKrauss well i think the CPU load is because JAVA, my database is in other server. I indexed some columns but i just gained some few ms.

Comment: @Alexandre Moraes yes i just have one more question. Is it a good practice to develop a REST API using BigQuery? I mean, i want fast responses and i dont really know how many requests per day i will have but perfomance and price is something i need to care and balance... It could be great if you know any use case working with BigQuery like this. Thanks both for your answers!

Comment: For dashboards and BigQuery the best answer is "BI Engine" - which only works with Data Studio (for now)

Comment: Alternatively, you could use [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) as your MongoDB cloud hosting. Then you can access it using [MongoDB Stitch](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/stitch) serverless platform to serve APIs, and use [MongoDB Charts](http://docs.mongodb.com/charts/master/) to create graphs from your data.

Comment: @Sergio Fonseca, regarding the REST API, Google provides a comprehensive documentation about API's for BigQuery, you can check here: [gitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis), [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest), [github](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery). Then you can see an overview of the documentation and check if it satisfies your demands. I also must point that BigQuery has some limits for query jobs such as 100 concurrent queries ( you can do more than that using --dry run), [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas).

Comment: Continuing, about BigQuery benefits you can read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery). In addition about a case of migrating from MongoDB to BigQuery, you can read this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/export-load-job-with-mongodb-bigquery-part-i-64a00eb5266b). Please, let me know if the information I provided was helpful or if you have any other doubts.